# How to 'un-nest' nested macros?

Tags: substitution

Sometimes I have to typeset documents with nested definitions like these:

```
\def\foo{\ensuremath{foo}\xspace}
\def\baz{\ensuremath{\beta}\xspace}
\def\qux{{\ensuremath{{\foo\mskip -3mu/\mskip -2mu\baz\mskip 2mu}}}\xspace}
\def\quux{\kern 0.2em\overline{\kern -0.2em quux}{}\xspace}
\def\corge{\ensuremath{\quux^{*0}}\xspace}

\newcommand{\grault}{\ensuremath{a^b_c \to \qux \corge}\xspace}
```

For some reasons that I can not explain for confidentiality obligations, I can not use directly nested macros like `\qux`, `\quux` and so on in some parts of my documents and I have to use their in full definition. Hence, my aim is to obtain the following macros automatically:

```
%\def\foo{\ensuremath{foo}\xspace}
%\def\baz{\ensuremath{\beta}\xspace}
%\def\qux{{\ensuremath{{\foo\mskip -3mu/\mskip -2mu\baz\mskip 2mu}}}\xspace}
%\def\quux{\kern 0.2em\overline{\kern -0.2em quux}{}\xspace}
%\def\corge{\ensuremath{\quux^{*0}}\xspace}

%\newcommand{\grault}{\ensuremath{a^b_c \to \qux \corge}\xspace}

\def\foo{\ensuremath{foo}\xspace}
\def\baz{\ensuremath{\beta}\xspace}
\def\qux{{\ensuremath{{\ensuremath{foo}\xspace\mskip -3mu/\mskip -2mu\ensuremath{\beta}\xspace\mskip 2mu}}}\xspace}
\def\quux{\kern 0.2em\overline{\kern -0.2em quux}{}\xspace}
\def\corge{\ensuremath{\kern 0.2em\overline{\kern -0.2em quux}{}\xspace^{*0}}\xspace}

\newcommand{\grault}{\ensuremath{a^b_c \to {\ensuremath{{\ensuremath{foo}\xspace\mskip -3mu/\mskip -2mu\ensuremath{\beta}\xspace\mskip 2mu}}}\xspace \ensuremath{\kern 0.2em\overline{\kern -0.2em quux}{}\xspace^{*0}}\xspace}\xspace}
```

Is there a way to do thisy?

Ps: I am aware that the 'extended' version of these macros is horrid.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}


\def\foo{\ensuremath{foo}\xspace}
\def\baz{\ensuremath{\beta}\xspace}
\def\qux{{\ensuremath{{\foo\mskip -3mu/\mskip -2mu\baz\mskip 2mu}}}\xspace}
\def\quux{\kern 0.2em\overline{\kern -0.2em quux}{}\xspace}
\def\corge{\ensuremath{\quux^{*0}}\xspace}

\newcommand{\grault}{\ensuremath{a^b_c \to \qux \corge}\xspace}
    

\begin{document}

\grault

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what your aim is.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, my english is not so fluently... I would obtain, for instance, `\grault` written in full without using `\qux` and `\corge`, but directly with their definitions, i.e. `\newcommand{\grault}{\ensuremath{a^b_c \to {\ensuremath{{\ensuremath{foo}\xspace ...`

Comment: Those `\ensuremath` and `\xspace` are bad to begin with. But I still don't understand what you mean. Simply replace `\foo` by its definition. What else?

Comment: @egreg Of course, I can do these substitutions manually, but my purpose was to ask if there is a way for doing these substitutions automatically with a script.

Comment: If I got it right, this is more a job for an editor than for latex... Or is there a latex-way to only fully expand all macros and retrieve the code?

Comment: If you fully expand a macro you have nothing left but text. \meaning and \tracingmacros=1 might help, but "replace all" is ultimately the way to go (until \csname pops up).